# Filtering CSV file based on row value

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a CSV file such as the one shown below that I need to filter based on values on a specific column. I cannot `Import-Csv`, because the file is too large and it takes a very long time. I managed to use an Excel based solution I found online but it is extremely inefficient and it takes hours for the script to run.

`Sample.csv`:

```
A,1,2,3,4,5
B,1,A,B,C,D
C,1,2,3,4
D,2,1,2,3
E,5,1,1,1
F,8,1,1,1
```

I would like the output to be all rows for which Column 2 is greater or equal than 2. That is:

`Output.csv`:

```
D,2,1,2,3
E,5,1,1,1
F,8,1,1,1
```

How could a more efficient solution to this problem would be developed?

Comment: You are almost reasking the same question as your last. Was it not working?

Comment: How many records are there in your input csv?

Comment: @Matt, I understand. My last question was Excel-based and I was looking for ways to do it outside of Excel. Also, my last question was about removing columns. In this one, it is about filtering based on row value.

Comment: @WalterMitty it can have up to 500k lines with 50 columns per csv.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Get-Content foo.csv | Where {[int]($_.Split(',')[1]) -ge 2}
```

Get-Content will read the CSV file one line at a time. The Where command will filter objects passed into it.  If the condition inside evals to $true the object gets passed on down the pipeline.  In this case, we split the line on a comma, grab the second field (zero-based index means index 1), cast it to `int` and then compare -ge (greater than or equal to) 2.  Note that in PowerShell, its type coercion is always based on the left hand side (LHS) of a binary operator like `-ge`.  Therefore you want to make sure the LHS is of type `int` so you are comparing ints and not strings.

Comment: The file is enormous apparently (Worked with this user recently). I would suggest using `-ReadCount 2000` at least for this.

Comment: @Matt Fair point, but that would require him to split the lines manually

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I'm not sure what the trade off is or if it is faster than using a stream reader

Comment: @Keith Hill thank you. This worked perfectly; however, as Matt mentioned these files are very large. Is there a way to integrate the -readcount into these code? I tried integrating it as a switch after the Get-Content and that did not work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try this but I'm not sure it will be faster: `Get-Content foo.csv -ReadCount 1024 | Foreach { foreach ($line in $_) { if ([int]($line.Split(',')[1]) -ge 2) { $line }}}`   You can play around with the ReadCount value to try to tune perf.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to access the CSV as a database table via OLE:

```
$datadir = 'C:\csv\folder'
$cs = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=$datadir;" +
      'Extended Properties="text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited";'

$cn = New-Object Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
$cn.ConnectionString = $cs

$cmd = $cn.CreateCommand()
$cmd.CommandText = 'SELECT * FROM [sample.csv] WHERE [col2] >= 2'

# fill a dataset with the query result
$adapter = New-Object Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter $cmd
$dataset = New-Object Data.DataSet
$adapter.Fill($dataset)

# export the first table from the dataset to a new CSV
$dataset.Tables[0] | Export-Csv 'C:\Temp\output.csv' -NoType

$cn.Close()
```

The above assumes that the path of your source CSV is `C:\csv\folder\sample.csv` and that the header of the second column is `col2`. The output CSV is created as `C:\temp\output.csv`. Adjust as needed.